# Pasar valores consulta mysql mediante javascript

Tags: php, javascript, html, mysql

Al realizar una consulta, muestro en una tabla los resultados, cada fila cuenta con un botón. Al pulsarlo muevo la información de la fila seleccionada a un textarea. El problema viene que al tener todos los botones el mismo identificador, java coge siempre la primera fila. (Solucionado).

https://jsfiddle.net/a50ue2bw/

El problema ahora es que al realizar la cuenta, coge los valores de la primera fila siempre. ¿Alguna solución?

```js
$('.button').on('click',calcular);
function calcular() {
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + $(this).closest('tr').find('#cantidad').val());
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + " "+ $(this).closest('tr').find('select option:selected').attr('value'));
    $('#pedido').val($('#pedido').val() + " "+ $(this).attr('nombre')+ "\n");
    
    var newPrice = parseFloat($('body').find('#categoria option:selected').attr('precio'));
    var cantidadt = parseFloat($('body').find('#cantidad').val());
    $("#cuenta").val(parseFloat($("#cuenta").val())+parseFloat(newPrice*cantidadt)+' €');
    $("#save").val(parseFloat($("#save").val())+parseFloat(newPrice*cantidadt));
    
     
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
while ($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                            ?>
                            <table>
                            <tr id="fila" value="<?php echo $datos["idevento"];?>">  
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["idevento"];?></td>  
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["idrecinto"];?></td>  
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["fecha"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["entradas"];?></td>
                                    <td><?php echo $datos["descripcion"];?></td>
                                    
                                    <td><select id="categoria" name="categoria" placeholder="Categoría">
                                    <?php
                                    
                                    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM categoria ;";  
                                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
                
                                    while ($datos2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                                    ?>
                                    <option value="<?php echo $datos2["idcategoria"];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos2["precio"];?>" ><?php echo $datos2["idcategoria"].' ('; echo $datos2["precio"].')';?>
                                    
                                    <?php
                            }
                            ?>
                                        </option>  
                                    </select></td>
                                <td><input id="cantidad" min="1" max="10" name="cantidad" type="number" placeholder="Cantidad"  required /></td>
                                <td><input class="button primary small" nombre="<?php echo $datos["idevento"];?>"  id="idevento" value="Añadir"></td>
                                
                                
                               </tr>  
                            

                            <?php
                            }
            
                            
        }
                          
                          ?>  
                            
                            </table> 
                        
                <div id="main">
                        <div class="inner">
                            <h1>Pedido</h1>
                            <textarea id="pedido" name="pedido" readonly="readonly"></textarea>
                            <input type="text" name="cuenta" id="cuenta" class="form-control" value=0 placeholder="Importe Total" required readonly="readonly" >
                            
                            <input type="text" name="save" id="save" class="form-control" value=0  style="display:none;" required>
                    </div>
                </div>
```

Comment: No entiendo muy bien la pregunta, pero si sabes el problema, sabes la solucion

Comment: Cada fila cuenta con un botón, al seleccionar cualquier botón de la tabla, java coge los valores de la primera fila, habiendo pulsado el botón de otra fila.

Comment: pues donde creas los botones le pasas por argumento a JAVASCRIPT el numero de fila o el id del <tr> o algo que sea identificador unico.

Comment: Por favor edita la pregunta para agregar el código aquí mismo, no en un sitio externo.

Comment: Usa 'idevento' para hacer que el boton solo afecte al el <tr> que tiene ese 'idevento'

Comment: ¿Cómo se haría?

Comment: Si me pides eso, yo te lo cambiaría muchas cosas, que quizás no es lo que deseas. De igual manera, si quieres te lo enseño, pero confirmamelo antes.

Comment: Ok, lo que quiero es que funcione.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lo primero de todo, cambiaria la creacion de la tabla dinamica que tienes. te los señalo asi **(n)**

**Primero te pongo como lo haria, y despues te digo el motivo y que se tiene que cambiar**

```
while ($datos=mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
?>
    <table> (1)
        <tr id="fila" (2) value="<?php echo $datos["idevento"];?>" (3)>  
                <td><?php echo $datos["idevento"];?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $datos["idrecinto"];?></td>  
                <td><?php echo $datos["fecha"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["entradas"];?></td>
                <td><?php echo $datos["descripcion"];?></td>
                <td><select id="categoria" (4) name="categoria" placeholder="Categoría">
                <?php
                    $query2 ="SELECT * FROM categoria ;"; (5) 
                    $result2 = mysqli_query($conexion, $query2);
                    while ($datos2=mysqli_fetch_array($result2)) {
                ?>
                        <option value="<?php echo $datos2["idcategoria"];?>" precio="<?php echo $datos2["precio"];?>" ><?php echo $datos2["idcategoria"].' ('; echo $datos2["precio"].')';?>
                <?php
                    }
                ?>
                        </option>  
                    </select></td>
                <td><input id="cantidad" (6) min="1" max="10" name="cantidad" type="number" placeholder="Cantidad"  required /></td>
                <td><input class="button primary small" nombre="<?php echo $datos["idevento"];?>"  id="idevento" (7) value="Añadir"></td>
           </tr>  
<?php
}
?>  
    </table>
```

**(1)** `<table>` esta dentro del `while`, ponlo fuera, es necesario, sino la tabla no estara bien formada.

**(2)** Ponle un `id` unico a cada `tr`, por ejemplo: `<tr id="<?php echo 'fila'. $datos['idevento']"` ..., de esta manera siempre podemos acceder a un `<tr>` sin mayores complicaciones.

**(3)** Usaremos nuestros propios atributos, es decir, en cada `<tr>` crearemos el atributo `idevento`, `idrecinto`, `fecha`... y los llenamos con los datos correspondientes, por ejemplo:

```
<tr id="<?php echo 'fila'. $datos['idevento']" value="<?php echo $datos['idevento'];?>"  idevento="<?php echo $datos['idevento'];?>" idrecinto="<?php echo $datos['idrecinto'];?>"
```

Esto sirve para poder recoger datos despues, sin muchas complicaciones, simplemente conociendo el `idevento`.

**(4)** Debes poner un `id` unico a tu `<select>`, sino lo vas hacer no lo pongas, pero no los repitas. Es como el caso **(2)**

**(5)** Evita el uso de `*` en tus querys, mejorara mucho el rendimiento si lo categorizas correctamente (usando el nombre del campo)

**(6) y (7)** El mismo caso que **(2)** y **(4)**, acostúmbrate a usar `id` únicas, sino las vas a usar no las pongas, y si la pones, que sean únicas, por que después cuando quieras acceder siempre te cogerá la primera ocurrencia, por no decir que el `HTML` estara mal construido.

---

Hasta aquí la construcción de la tabla dinámica.

Ahora vamos con el `JS`

Aquí te voy a poner la función, y te la voy comentando.

```
$("button").each(function(index, el) { //aqui entramos en bucle y hara esto para cada 'button'
    var idEvento = $(this).parent("tr").attr("idevento"); //Capturamos el idEvento al que haremos referencia
    $(this).on('click', function(){
        var html = "";
        var cantidad = $("tr[idevento="+idEvento+"]").attr("cantidad"); //capturamos la cantidad, recuerda que el paso anterior lo pusimos como atributo
        var nombre = $("tr[idevento="+idEvento+"]").attr("nombre"); //capturamos el nombre, recuerda que el paso anterior lo pusimos como atributo
        var categoria = $("select[id=categoria"+idEvento+"] option:selected").attr("value"); //capturamos la categoria usando idEvento, recuerda que el id lo cambiamos arriba

        html = "<p>"+cantidad+"</p>";
        html += "<p>"+categoria+"</p>";
        html += "<p>"+nombre+"</p>";
        //llenamos el textarea
        $("#pedido").val(html); //no se si el textarea funciona con val() o html()
        //calculamos los datos, pero usando idEvento, que sera unico, lo cambiamos en en la construccion de la tabla (arriba)
        var newPrice = parseFloat($("select[id=categoria"+idEvento+"] option:selected").attr("precio"));
        var cantidadt = parseFloat($("#cantidad").val());
        $("#cuenta").val(parseFloat($("#cuenta").val()) + parseFloat(newPrice * cantidadt) + " €");
        $("#save").val(parseFloat($("#save").val()) + parseFloat(newPrice * cantidadt));
    });             
});
```

Y FIN, con esto te debe funcionar, yo lo hecho en una función anónima por que me gusta mas, siéntete libre de hacerlo como mas te guste ;)

---

Edicion me habia dejado un punto ('.') entre `button` y `each`, esta corregido!

Comment: Javascript no funciona al pulsar los botones

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ftekLg90/

Comment: en el fiddle no te funcionara nunca, no tocan PHP, pruebalo en localhost

Comment: ademas me dejado un punto, lo edito!

Comment: Tiene que haber otro error, sigue sin funcionar

Comment: Lo estas probando en localhost?

Comment: Sí, en el jsfiddle está como lo tengo ahora

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/ftekLg90/#&togetherjs=tmckGFj2gA

Comment: entra aqui, es un fiddle compartido

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111712/discussion-between-fidel-and-srsole).